# Wait for an ajax to display result

Tags: jquery, deferred, promise

I'm having to trouble to achieve the following task. 
I have three functions

```
function f1(param1) {
    var d = $.deferred();
    // ajax call with data param1
   d.resolve(res0, res1);
    return d.promise();
}
function f2(param2) {
    var d = $.deferred();
    // ajax call with data param2
    d.resolve(res2);
    return d.promise();
}

function f3(param3) {
   var d = $.deferred();
   // ajax call with data param3
   d.resolve(res3);
   return d.promise();
}
```

I'm running them like this :

```
$.when(f1(param1),f2(pram2),f3(param3)).done(function(res,res2,res3){

});
```

My requirement is :

if res2 is empty  run `f2(res[1])`. once done display `res[0] + f2(res[1]) +  res3`

else display `res[0] + res2 + res3`

Is there any one who can help me with this using jQuery/promises?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, `res` and `res3` are independent of each other, but `res2` *may* depend on `res[1]` if the *initial* call to `f2` produced an empty result.

If that happens, you need to call `f2` again.

So:

```
$.when( f1(p1), f2(p2), f3(p3)).then(function(res, res2, res3) {
    if (!res2) {             // substitute appropriate "empty" test
        res2 = f2(res[1]);   // call f2 again, getting a new promise
    }
    return $.when(res, res2, res3);  // create new compound promise
}).done(function(res, res2, res3) {
    // do your stuff
});
```

The idea being that the inner call to `$.when()` will automatically resolve if `res`, `res2` and `res3` are already "normal" return values, but if `res2` is substituted for a new `promise` the `$.when` call will wait for *that* to be resolved before continuing.

Comment: thank you for you answer. in the line "return $.when(res,res2,res3)" you mean well $.when(f1(p1),res2, f3(p3)). If so i think i will send another ajax call to get a result that i already have : res[0] and res[3]. res[0] and res3 are ready to be dispplayed that don't depend of anything. It's only res2 which depends on res[1]

Comment: @Bes-mM-bes no, that line means exactly what I said.  When you pass something that isn't a promise to `$.when` it's implicitly considered "resolved", so passing `(res, promise, res3)` will only wait for the middle value to be (re)resolved - the other parameters will be passed to the `.done` call as normal values.